# Retrieve matched array element in Elastic Search query

Tags: elasticsearch

In a movie database, I store the ratings (0 to 5 stars) given by users to each of the movies. I have the following document structure indexed in Elastic Search (version 1.2.2)

```
"_index": "my_index"
"_type": "film",
"_id": "6629",
"_source": {
  "id": "6629",
  "title": "Fight Club",
  "ratings" : [
    { "user_id" : 1234, "rating_value" : 3 },
    { "user_id" : 4567, "rating_value" : 2 },
    { "user_id" : 7890, "rating_value" : 1 }
    .....
  ]
}

"_index": "my_index"
"_type": "film",
"_id": "6630",
"_source": {
  "id": "6630",
  "title": "Pulp Fiction",
  "ratings" : [
    { "user_id" : 1234, "rating_value" : 1 },
    { "user_id" : 7654, "rating_value" : 2 },
    { "user_id" : 4321, "rating_value" : 5 }
    .....
  ]
}
```

etc ...

My goal is to get, in a single search, all the movies rated by a user (let's say user 1234), **alongside with the rating_value**

If I do the following search

```
GET my_index/film/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "ratings.user_id": "1234"
    }
  }
}
```

I get, for all matched movies, the whole document, and then, I have to parse the whole ratings array to find out which element of the array has matched my query and what is the rating_value associated with the user_id 1234.

Ideally, I would like the result of this query to be

```
"hits": [ {
  "_index": "my_index"
  "_type": "film",
  "_id": "6629",
  "_source": {
    "id": "6629",
    "title": "Fight Club",
    "ratings" : [
      { "user_id" : 1234, "rating_value" : 3 }, // <= only the row that matches the query
    ]
  },
  "_index": "my_index"
  "_type": "film",
  "_id": "6630",
  "_source": {
    "id": "6630",
    "title": "Pulp Fiction",
    "ratings" : [
      { "user_id" : 1234, "rating_value" : 1 },  // <= only the row that matches the query
    ]
  }
} ]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't obtain the ideal result you want as the _source will always be the exact same JSON as the one you indexed. However, you can use aggregations to get the information you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to retrieve the values using **aggregations**, as stated in my previous comment.

Here follows how I did this.

First, the mapping I used :

```
PUT test/movie/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "title":{
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "ratings": {
      "type": "nested"
    }
  }
}
```

I chose not to index the title, but you could use **fields** attribute and keep it as a "raw" field.

Then, the movies indexed :

```
PUT test/movie/6629
{
  "title": "Fight Club",
  "ratings" : [
    { "user_id" : 1234, "rating_value" : 3 },
    { "user_id" : 4567, "rating_value" : 2 },
    { "user_id" : 7890, "rating_value" : 1 }
  ]
}


PUT test/movie/4456
{
  "title": "Jumanji",
  "ratings" : [
    { "user_id" : 1234, "rating_value" : 4 },
    { "user_id" : 4567, "rating_value" : 3 },
    { "user_id" : 4630, "rating_value" : 5 }
  ]
}

PUT test/movie/6547
{
  "title": "Hook",
  "ratings" : [
    { "user_id" : 1234, "rating_value" : 4 },
    { "user_id" : 7890, "rating_value" : 1 }
  ]
}
```

The aggregation query is :

```
GET test/movie/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_movie": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ratings_by_user": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "ratings"
          },"aggs": {
            "for_user_1234": {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "ratings.user_id": "1234"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "rating_value": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "ratings.rating_value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, here is the output produced when executing this query against the previous documents :

```
"aggregations": {
  "by_movie": {
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "Fight Club",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "ratings_by_user": {
              "doc_count": 3,
              "for_user_1234": {
                 "doc_count": 1,
                 "rating_value": {
                    "buckets": [
                       {
                          "key": 3,
                          "key_as_string": "3",
                          "doc_count": 1
                       }
                    ]
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "Hook",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "ratings_by_user": {
              "doc_count": 2,
              "for_user_1234": {
                 "doc_count": 1,
                 "rating_value": {
                    "buckets": [
                       {
                          "key": 4,
                          "key_as_string": "4",
                          "doc_count": 1
                       }
                    ]
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "Jumanji",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "ratings_by_user": {
              "doc_count": 3,
              "for_user_1234": {
                 "doc_count": 1,
                 "rating_value": {
                    "buckets": [
                       {
                          "key": 4,
                          "key_as_string": "4",
                          "doc_count": 1
                       }
                    ]
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
```

}

It's a bit tedious because of the nested syntax, but you'll be able to retrieve the rating of the provided user (here, 1234) for each movie.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It works fine but I still face 2 issues : 1/ I cannot aggregate by movie id instead of movie title. 2/ I cannot set an offset ('from' in ES) for the aggregated results I get. For the moment I'm trying to solve those 2 issues - but thanks for pointing this path

Comment: 1) this is because the id isn't indexed. You can solve this by adding an "id" field to your mapping and index it as "not_analyzed". Then, update the "by_movie" aggregation to relate to the "id" field.

Comment: 2) According to the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html#search-request-from-size), it seems that the from/size parameters are applied to the results, not to the aggregations.

Answer (score 2):

Store ratings as nested documents (or children), then you will be able to query them individually.

A good explanation for the difference between nested documents and children can be found here: http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, they're already stored as nested documents. But the query still returns the whole "parent" (i.e. film) document

Comment: (or did you imply that I should use the "Parent & Child" structure instead of nested documents ?)

Comment: Ah then you can make a nested query, which will give you individual elements. The only issue there would be getting parent properties (i.e. movie name) as well. From that POV, parent-child structure is easier to work with.